# What is the meaning of full-width link and half-width link in peripheral specifications of CPU/microprocessors?

Tags: cpu, bus, intel-itanium

I am studying the bus characteristics of microprocessors for a seminar that is part of a course of computing system foundations that I am taking at the university. I am studying [Intel Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium). In [this website](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Itanium_2/Intel-Itanium%209310%20LW80603003243AA.html) I found the following description (I am just showing the part I am interested in) about one of the processors in this family:

> **Intel Itanium 2 9310**
>
> **Integrated Peripherals and Components:**
> Other Peripherals:
>
> 1. Two DDR3 memory controllers
> 2. Quick Path Interconnect with 4 full-width and 2 half-width links

I read a bit about [Quick Path Interconnect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect), but I was not able to discover the meaning of full-width and half-width links.

Can anyone tell me what full-width and half-width links mean in this context?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thought producing question, how many bits, is a full quick path interconnect, if you answer that question you have answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Intel [Quick Path Interconnect Introduction](https://www.intel.ca/content/dam/doc/white-paper/quick-path-interconnect-introduction-paper.pdf) Whitepaper, in the **Physical Layer** section:

> [image]
>
> Each full link is comprised of twenty 1-bit lanes that use differential signaling
> and are DC coupled.
>
> At full-width that would be 20 bits, at half-width 10 bits and at quarter-width 5 bits.

If, for whatever reason, a link is unable to be established at full-width then it appears that the interconnect can negotiate down to whatever link width is available.